# How to hide gridview row in asp.net using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I am developing one application using asp.net and jquery where i have one gridview. I am trying to hide rows of grid view based on certain condition. I tried with some jquery code as below.

```
for (var k = 0; k < result.length; k++)
            {
                $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {

                    if($(this).val()==result[k])
                    {

                      //Want to hide kth row of gridview 
                    }
                });

            }
```

And as soon as i hide the row then i want to break the inner loop. I tried by putting break but it is not working. May I have some inputs on the above problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo need to fetch the parent row in which hidden filed lies and hide it.

```
 $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {

    if($(this).val()==result[k])
    {

      //$(this).closest('tr').css('display','none');
      $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled',true);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

[**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function searches up the DOM tree i.e selected element's ancestor and `return false` is used to break out of `each()` function.

Comment: I am struggling for this piece of code from past week. This is working like charm. Thank you... I am new to this asp.net world. again thank you very much

Comment: Sorry for asking again doubts. Suppose if i have checkbox in that row and instead of removing entire row just if i want to disable that checkbox then what I would have to do?

Comment: I tried as below.     $(this).closest("td").find("input:CheckBox").attr("checked", false); But still i am able to check and uncheck checkbox.